# jqGrid hide row when table is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table and I would like to hide rows based on a condition.  I have been trying to hide the row in the gridComplete event but that does not seem to work.  My gridComplete event looks like this:

```
gridComplete: function() {
        for(i = 0; i < rowsToHide.length; i++) {
            $("#" + rowsToHide[i], "#myTable").hide();
        }
}
```

I'm not sure if I can technically hide the row like this or if there is another way I need to do this.  I'm basically looking to hide a set of rows based on some criteria once I have the data set returned from the server.  I would like to hide these rows as soon as I load my jqGrid table.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you solved your problem already?

Comment: No I still have not had any luck.  I haven't found much documentation and have started digging through jqGrid source code to figure out why I can't get this to work.

Comment: Could you check if the value of the length property of $("#" + rowsToHide[i], "#myTable") is 1? If it's not your selector is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for hiding rows, however the solution you posted should work but has some tiny issues. The fact it isn't working could be because of the typo you made: rowToHide[i] -> rowsToHide[i] or the row ID's in the array are wrong. Check your array for that, also check if the function is being called.

The issues are that when you hide rows and the height of your grid is set to **auto** it will not adjust the size properly, also if you show rownumbers in your grid they are not sequential anymore. This problems can be fixed manually.